# ssh login using public/private key exchange authorized_keys not working?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, authentication, ssh-tunnel, public-key

I am trying to login from one ubuntu box to another using public/private keys with ssh, but it is not working..

```
 OMD[live]:~/.ssh$ ssh -l myuser -v -i /test/sites/live/.ssh/id.rsa.myuser xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
 OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
 debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
 debug1: Applying options for *
 debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
 debug1: Connection established.
 debug1: identity file /omd/sites/live/.ssh/id.rsa.myuser type -1
 debug1: identity file /omd/sites/live/.ssh/id.rsa.myuser-cert type -1
 debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
 debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH*
 debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
 debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
 debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
 debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
 debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
 debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 26:da:c8:3f:b6:e1:4c:0f:31:58:e0:06:4f:ac:a8:86
 debug1: Host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
 debug1: Found key in /omd/sites/live/.ssh/known_hosts:22
 debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
 debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
 debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
 debug1: Trying private key: /omd/sites/live/.ssh/id.rsa.myuser
 debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
 debug1: Next authentication method: password
 myuser@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx's password:
```

I am not sure why? It looks like it attempts to use private key but there is no error message after, only a password prompt.

This same method works on other boxes except this one..

Any ideas?

Comment: If you got other ways to access this machine, look in `/var/log/auth.log` for authentication errors and post them please

Comment: check strictmode and the permission of the .ssh user directory (not group/world readable).

Answer (score 0):

You must have the public key (`/omd/sites/live/.ssh/id.rsa.myuser.pub`) in the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys in order to public/private work, otherwise the destination system will refuse the key and the client just goes to the next valid method (this case is password because you don't have any other keys)